# Executing a Classic ASP Encrypted file in browser

Tags: asp-classic, encryption, file-security

I have encrypted my ASP File. But when i run it in browser it fails. How to execute that asp file so that my application could run ? 
how to decrypt it, it is encrypted using a tool , how do I decrypt it while execution ? I don't want that anybody whom I give that file , sees the code of the file , but could only execute it and use it.

Comment: Ummmm.....decrypt it first?

Comment: @Diodeus : how to decrypt it, actually i encrypted it using a tool , now how do i decrypt it while execution ? i don't want that anybody sees the code of the file.

Comment: The code runs on the SERVER not the client. How would anyone ever see it?

Comment: What tool did you use to encrypt it?

Comment: @Diodeus : I am using it on local system.

Comment: @RicoSuave : tool is ASPEncrypt

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I understand:

ASPEncrypt is a component you can use to encrypt files using ASP or ASP.NET. It is NOT  a tool to encrypt your ASP(.NET) source code files with.

You're looking for something like [Microsoft script encoder](http://www.virtualconspiracy.com/content/articles/breaking-screnc) (I don't know if it's still available), you want your sourcecode to be unreadable right?
There are tools that claim to do this, but there isn't one I know of that can't be reversed. So it's only a small obstacle if someone **really** wants to get their hands on your code.

[Here](http://www.vbs2exe.com/encrypt-vbs.html) are some [more tools](http://dennisbabkin.com/screnc/) that claim to do this.

I hope one of them suits your needs.